# how to filter a value from a long string

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I need to filter a certain value from a large paragraph.

Here is an example string:

> TitleCore PHP programming Prentice Hall PTR core seriesAuthorsLeon
>   Atkinson, Zeev  SuraskiEdition3, illustratedPublisherPrentice Hall
>   Professional, 2004***ISBN0130463469, 9780130463463***Length1072
>   pagesSubjectsComputers › Networking › General Computers / Internet /
>   Web Page Design Computers / Networking / General Computers /
>   Programming / General Computers / Programming Languages / General
>   Computers / Web / General Electronic books PHP (Computer program
>   language) Web sites Web sites/ Design &nbspExport CitationBiBTeX
>   EndNote RefMan

First I need to extract this value `ISBN0130463469, 9780130463463`, then filter the above to `9780130463463`.

I have a lot of paragraphs like this. The only identifier is the text "ISBN".

Answer (score 3):

Using [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and a pattern such as:

```
/ISBN\d+, (\d+)/
```

Should work. Also, you can wrap the first `\d+` in parenthesis if you need this number, too.

Comment: Working example, btw: http://regexr.com?2vamn & IDEOne Version (as a PHP script): http://www.ideone.com/LFq3V

Comment: I guess these numbers are the ISBN-10s and ISBN-13s of those books, so the first `\d+` should be `[xX\d]+`

Comment: @Niko: If that's the case, then correct, it should be changed to a class. I don't know much about ISBN format, so if there should be non-numeric characters allowed this should be modified.

Comment: @BradChristie. An ISBN-10 may end with an `X` (it's a mod-11 check digit, and 10 is represented as X). An ISBN-13 will always be purely numeric. Any ISBN-10 has an equivalent ISBN-13 (prefix with `978` and recalculate the check digit), but not all ISBN-13s have equivalent ISNB-10s (some newer ISBN-13s begin with `979`). The example given seems to be in the format "ISBN[ISBN-10], [ISBN-13]". So Nico is correct that the regex should allow for the letter `X`.

Answer (score -2):

str_ireplace('ISBN', '', 'ISBN0130463469');